# How to build a 220v ~40 amp WIFI switch (for pool pump or similar)

Tags: smart-home, wifi

I'm looking for ideas and suggestions to build a 220v ~ 40 amp wifi switch for controlling my pool pump so that it can replace my mechanical timer.

Very few devices are available on the market. There are both relatively expensive and according to the reviews don't live up to expectations in terms of reliability and build:

- [WiOn Outdoor Wi-Fi Smart Box](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00ZYLTJ16)
- [Generic WIFI Relay Module 6000W High Power 220V 30A](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07VNS7V9J)
- [KTNNKG 30amps Smart Pump Switch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07DW9JN22)

The main issue seems to come from the terminal connections not being big or sturdy enough for 10 gage wire.

Looking at the [Migro Outdoor Smart Wi-Fi Outlet Box](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07THD8VBN) it seems they have combined a contactor with a sonoff switch which seems like the best option. This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aml0VGzNXEo) explains how a contactor works. Migro are charging around $140 whereas the contactor on it's own only costs $14 [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07T7ZLF7S) and the sonoff switch $8 [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07KP8THFG).

Does building one seem the best / cheapest option?

Comment: I would also suggest to build something based on Sonoff. I like how Migro added a range extender.

Comment: What's best questions often lead to no answers because people do not know on what criteria they are supposed to measure *best*. Can you add what's important to you?

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing for my pool pump. I installed the KTNNKG 30A switch, and it has been working well. But, I hear that it will likely burn out. Did you eventually figure out a solution, using a contactor? I think a setup like the Migro, would work, but not sure how to wire the wifi switch to the contactor, or which contactor to buy. Thank!

Comment: Well, in theory, if you use a [Migro contactor with a 120VAC coil](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07YVMYBL8?th=1), you may be able to use your current setup to turn that on and put the load on the Migro contactor, which you think may last longer ! Just saying. I dont really know about the durability of either the KTNNKG or the Migro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you've answered your own question :)

Yes - a wifi controllable interface (likr Sonoff) hooked to act as the trigger for the contactor relay is probably your best/cheapest option. Saves you the issue of coding your own I/O control and easily manages overall power requirements.